# How to validate a message in pcap?

Tags: parsing, wireshark, pcap, jnetpcap

I have a requirement to expand required tree in decoded parameters of pcap file and validate a message in it.

Example:
Open "Transmission Control Protocol" as shown in screenshot and and validate for the message "This is an ACK to the segment in frame: 278".

Need to develop an automation script in Java for validating messages in pcap files . Currently am using jnetpcap lib.
Appreciate your inputs!. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't, without protocol analysis by yourself. A pcap file doesn't include such massages.

The message "This is an ACK to the segment in frame: 278" was generated by wireshark after TCP session analysis by itself. Even the frame number 278 was assigned by wireshark. A pcap file only contains packets' data.